# Greatest not null column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I need to update a row with a formula based on the largest value of two DATETIME columns. I would normally do this:

```
GREATEST(date_one, date_two)
```

However, both columns are allowed to be NULL. I need the greatest date even when the other is NULL (of course, I expect NULL when both are NULL) and `GREATEST()` returns NULL when one of the columns is NULL.

This seems to work:

```
GREATEST(COALESCE(date_one, date_two), COALESCE(date_two, date_one))
```

But I wonder... am I missing a more straightforward method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`COALESCE(GREATEST(date_one, date_two), date_one, date_two)`

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much. I just hope I'll never need to generalize this for **n** columns... ;-P

Comment: Ok, but what it there are more than 2 columns involved?  What if there are 10 columns?

Comment: For n-columns: `COALESCE(GREATEST(date_one, date_two.. date_n), date_one, date_two, .. date_n)`

Comment: @SanjayVerma Your generalization for `n` columns isn't entirely correct. If any of the dates are `NULL`, the inner call to `GREATEST(date_one, date_two, ... date_n)` will return `NULL`, which would cause the enclosing `COALESCE(GREATEST(...), date_one, date_two, ... date_n)` to return whichever date happens to be listed first and isn't `NULL`, which isn't necessarily the greatest date.

Comment: @NickMuise Good point!

Answer (score 1):

My solution for multiple columns is:

```
SELECT NULLIF(
  GREATEST(
    NVL(NULL,     to_date('01011980','ddmmyyyy')), --COLUMN 1
    NVL(sysdate,  to_date('01011980','ddmmyyyy')), --COLUMN 2
    NVL(NULL,     to_date('01011980','ddmmyyyy')), --COLUMN 3
    NVL(sysdate-1,to_date('01011980','ddmmyyyy'))  --COLUMN 4
  ),to_date('01011980','ddmmyyyy')
) as greatest_date
FROM DUAL;
```