# Handling Null in Greatest function in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to compare multiple date columns with each other and create a new column "latest_date", which is basically the greatest of them all.

For this we could use the `GREATEST()` function (DOC: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/greatest). The problem is that this function's output is null if any of the compared columns is null.

I have read multiple solutions for this here:

- [Handling Null in Greatest function in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186283/handling-null-in-greatest-function-in-oracle)
- [Avoiding NULL return value with GREATEST function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530880/avoiding-null-return-value-with-greatest-function)
- [Greatest not null column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684090/greatest-not-null-column)

Most of them propose to use the "COALESCE" function as follows:

```
GREATEST(
    COALESCE(a, b, c),
    COALESCE(b, c, a),
    COALESCE(c, a, b)
)
```

This is OK if we have just 2 or 3 columns, but does not escalate well when handling many columns (some with them containing nulls).

In my use case, I'm using Snowpark Dataframes (along  with Snowflake SQL) and I handle most of these date columns in my tables/dataframes in a "generic way" so **I don't know in advance how many columns I will be comparing.**

Could someone think of a workaround for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74529349/43992

Comment: [How to use `GREATEST()` in Snowflake with null values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527418/how-to-use-greatest-in-snowflake-with-null-values)  - my personal favorite is ARRAY_MAX/ARRAY_MIN - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689938/5070879

Comment: This is somehow useful. The problem here is that the casting to array/variant is not straightforward in Snowpark as it is in plain SQL (Snowflake). I guess the best solution would be to join the values in the multiple date columns into one array_variant column and the use 'ARRAY_MAX"..

Comment: ARRAY_MAX is not yet available as a function in Snowpark (< 1.6.1) in snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ARRAY_MAX](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/1.7.0/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.array_max) could be used with Snowpark:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import array_max,array_construct
from snowflake.snowpark.types import IntegerType

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df = session.create_dataframe([[None, None, None], [1, 2, 3], [None, 1, 2]],
                                  schema=["col1", "col2", "col3"])
    return df.select("col1", "col2", "col3",
                     array_max(array_construct("col1", "col2", "col3"))
                     .cast(IntegerType()).alias("greatest_col"))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [ponder / modin](https://ponder.io/) with normal pandas syntax. After connecting to snowflake, we create a temp table on Snowflake with two date columns (you would not have to do this if you already have the data in Snowflake):

```
    >> df = modin.pandas.DataFrame(data={'A': ['1993-06-09', '1993-11-24'], 'B': ['1993-11-24', np.NaN]})
    >> date_df = df.astype('datetime64[ns]')
    >> date_df 
               A          B
    0 1993-06-09 1993-11-24
    1 1993-11-24        NaT
```

Then max() should work on top of Snowflake.

```
    >> date_df.max() 
    A   1993-11-24
    B   1993-11-24
    Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
    >> date_df.min(axis=1)
    0   1993-06-09
    1          NaT
    dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Unfortunately, because this is executing on Snowflake, Ponder still is not handling NaN values exactly the way pandas would (bug filed), so a fillna is needed (and it should scale because Ponder is essentially doing the same coalesce in the underlying generated SQL.

```
>> date_df.fillna('1970-01-01').max(axis=1)
0   1993-11-24
1   1993-11-24
```

Another solution might be to write an apply lambda and execute that on Snowflake through ponder. The lambda gets translated into a UDF which is executed on the warehouse side (without copying the data). I've filed a bug for the NaT handling here w/ max - in general, Ponder should match the semantics of pandas.

Comment: Ok,  this makes sense. We would need a Snowpark.DataFrame to pd.DataFrame conversion though, which is not recommendable usually in terms on performance on the server side. I guess this is a valid solution though.